# Magento - list.phtml filtering product collection not giving correct pagination

Tags: magento, collections, pagination, product, catalog

I'm trying to filter list.phtml to suit my needs which is only showing products based of an value of the attribute. The original code to load the product collection is:

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
```

To do the filtering I have got the code:

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();

$cat_id = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
   ->addAttributeToFilter('language', array('eq' => array('English')))
   ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
   ->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id));


$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
```

This works however the pagination and items total number (generated from toolbar.phtml and pager.phtml are incorrect. For example the original product collection has the correct pagination of 7 pages and 10 products per page.

However when I use the filter shown above the pagination shows the same 7 pages and every filtered book on one page (there are 18 English books, so 7 pages of the 18 books which are duplicated).

Please can someone help me in solving this pagination issue.

Thanks.

The SQL for the collection is as follows:

```
 SELECT `e`.*, `at_language`.`value` AS `language`, `cat_index`.`position`
 AS `cat_index_position` FROM `catalog_product_entity`
 AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar`
 AS `at_language` ON (`at_language`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) 
 AND (`at_language`.`attribute_id` = '1002') 
 AND (`at_language`.`store_id` = 0) INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index`
 AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 
 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='38' 
 AND cat_index.is_parent=1 WHERE (at_language.value = 'English')
```

Comment: could you post the SQL that is generated for your collection? You can get it with $_productCollection->getSelect()->__toString()

Comment: I edited the question to show the SQL which is based of the collection code in your answer, Thanks.

Comment: see the addition to my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you get wrong a product count because the product visibility filter is missing. Try adding it like this:

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
   ->addAttributeToFilter('language', array('eq' => array('English')))
   ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
   ->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id))
   ->setVisibility(
       Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds()
   );
```

addition:

the custom collection you set to the `list.phtml` will not be the same the system uses in the paginator. The paginator block `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar` will get the original product collection from `$this->_getProductCollection()` ([see here](https://github.com/varinen/solvingmagento_1.7.0/blob/master/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php#L158)), which does not have your filter.

I'm afraid, a change to the collection in the template file is not enough. You might have to override the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` block, specifically, its function `_getProductCollection()` to implement the necessary filtering.

addition 2

A proposed override for the function `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List::_getProductCollection`:

```
protected function _getProductCollection()
{ 
    $collection = parent::_getProductCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('language', array('eq' => array('English')));
    $this->_productCollection = $collection;

    return $this->_productCollection;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have added this but I'm still getting the same result. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: If he's using multiple stores he could get a different result too, if so he shold also add in a store filter :)

Comment: I have just tried ' ->addStoreFilter(1) ' but I'm getting the same result, is this the right code to add the store filter?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm still a beginner in this area of Magento. I have had a look around the files. Is the file I need to do an override for 'Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php'. Also would the syntax for writing the filters here be the same as previously in my template files?

Comment: yes, the block class to rewrite is in the file Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php. You can do a simpler syntax there since you only have to add an attribute to filter. See my another addition to the answer for a proposed rewrite of the function `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List::_getProductCollection`

Comment: I created the override and used your addition 2 code. It does exactly as I needed. Thank you for your help! Unfortunately I need 15 reputation points to up vote :( Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

Use this in your list.phtml file:

```
$_productCollection->clear()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id', array('eq' => 63))
    ->load();
```